# Google Apps Script - Sheets email reminder and data gathering

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet which contains a number of cells which need to be updated by individuals on a weekly basis. Each cell has in an adjacent cell, the email address of the person who needs to update it. For various reasons I am trying to avoid giving people access to this sheet directly and was wondering if it were possible to email those users each week, with a form through which they can submit the relevant data?

Comment: Sure.  Most beginners tend to use Google Forms and then use an onFormSubmit trigger to capture the form submission.  More experienced programmers tend to roll their own form via HTML and JavaScript.  The latter provides greater flexibility and interactivity but it comes at the expense of greater complexity.  It's your choice.

Comment: Also I forgot to point out that forms have to be filled out on a server.  So emailing a form doesn't  really work.  You can email them a link to a form and have them fill it out online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, for example you could send them an email with GmailApp [1] with the form URL [2] so they can fill it.

When each user submit the form you can use a onFormSUbmit trigger [3] to collect the email and the data from the form, so after you can compare each email with the values in the sheet email column, and based on that you can edit the adjacent cell using SpreadsheetApp [4].

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getPublishedUrl()

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events

[4] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet